# How to get a free debian installation image?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, firmware, free-software

According to a [recent decision](https://www.debian.org/vote/2022/vote_003) Debian now only offers non-free installation images.  How to get a free one?  I tried to search the web for one and to change the offered one to remove the non-free firmware, but I couldn't get it to work completely.

Edit: I can't add a comment somehow, so here: "@StephenKitt I tried to add this, but couldn't figure out how to add it to the image (and adding it to the configuration only at boot time wasn't an option, because I don't know (yet?) for certain whether this will be early enough to not have any non free software run)."

Edit 2: Second comment: "@JaromandaX thanks!  That's what I did."

Comment: Are you concerned about having “non-free” components on your installation medium itself, or on the installed system? If the latter, isn’t the `firmware=never` boot option sufficient?

Comment: By the way, if you're anxious about that, "where possible we will include ways for users to disable this at boot (boot menu option, kernel command line etc.)." is pretty far-reaching. It does require you to select something when you boot the installer, but it will then not make use non-free firmware contained in the image. (I mean, your computer still is chock-full of non-free firmware, just that it's already in the system and doesn't have to get loaded by the operating system at boot)

Comment: yes, at the bootloader prompt is early enough to avoid *Linux* loading any non-free firmware, because Linux isn't running yet. Note that *nothing* is early enough "to not have any non free software run", because without non-free software, your mainboard doesn't even power on, your CPU doesn't start to be a CPU, your RAM doesn't get initialized, your USB controllers don't speak USB, your network card doesn't network… In other words: just because no proprietary firmware is loaded from your USB drive, your harddrive or SSD doesn't mean *at all* that your system isn't running proprietary firmware!

Comment: I still am all for hitting vendors with a shovel everytime they add closed source firmware to their system, up to the point where they publish the firmware that they are already running. It's just that the debian system will not load non-free firmware it doesn't think it *needs*, so if your system works with loafing free firmware only, only that will get loaded. If it doesn't work – well what do you gain?

Comment: One possible way if you're unsure about it - Install Debian 11 - upgrade to 12 without adding `non-free non-free-firmware` to the apt source config (it really doesn't add that much time to the install process)

Answer (score 4):

I’m not aware of any installation images of Debian 12 with no “non-free” firmware, however it is possible to entirely disable the installation of this firmware. No “non-free” software is included other than non-free firmware, so this ensures that no non-free software runs from the installation medium or any downloaded package.

To do this, [add the `firmware=never` boot option](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch02s02.en.html) in the installer. On a UEFI system:

- when the installer shows the “Graphical install”, “Install” etc. menu, choose the option you’re interested in, then press <kbd>E</kbd>
- in the editing screen, move down three lines (to the line starting with `linux`)
- at the end of the line, add `firmware=never`
- press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot

This will start the installer and skip firmware detection. No firmware will be loaded or installed on the system, and the non-free firmware repositories will be disabled.